# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions:) No matching distribution found for tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, installation

While installing TensorFlow for my pc the following error appeared

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement TensorFlow 
>   (from versions:) No matching distribution found for TensorFlow

I have a 64-bit Widows operating system.
And Python 3.7.0 64-bit. I already updated my pip from version 10.0 to 18.0 still error remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `Python 3.6`

From [tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows), It doesn't show support for `Python 3.7` yet. So maybe that's the issue. Although Python 3.7 has been released there are some Issues regarding the import because of the `async` variable, And even this thread shows the same solution. [Is python 3.7.x supported with Tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17022). So suggest you downgrade to `Python 3.6 (64bit)` and try again.

Comment: apparetly u were right there was lack of support fro python 3.7 at time

Answer (score 0):

Refer the link for TensorFlow supported version for python

```
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip
```

upgrade pip to version 20

```
C:\>pip --version
pip 20.0.2 from c:\python37_64\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)
```

then execute the following command

```
C:\>pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow_cpu-2.1.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

or

```
C:\>pip install tensorflow
```

Then check for the packages installed

```
C:\>pip list
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error:

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow== (from versions: 0.12.1, ...)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==

Check your comment. If there is a space between '==' and TensorFlow version, you will get an error. Below you can see an example for installing Tensorflow 1.15.
Wrong one:

```
pip install tensorflow== 1.5
```

Correct one:

```
pip install tensorflow==1.15
```